# Express and mongoose app gets error 404 when one route is below another but works when its above

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, routes

Im building a node.js app with express and I got an error in one of my routes, as you can see here the /hola route is below the /:marketId route and when I try to access the /hola route I get 404 Error not found. And the console logs **{ CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "hola" at path "_id" for model "Market"**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Market = require('../models/Market');
const Product = require('../models/Product');

const productRouter = require('./product');

router.use('/:marketId/products', productRouter);

// Description Show all Markets
// @route GET /markets

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const markets = await Market.find().lean();
        res.render('markets/index', {
            markets
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.render('error/404');
    }
});

// ADD --------------------------------

// description: Show add market page
//@route GET /markets/add

router.get('/add', (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.render('markets/add');
    } catch (err) {
        res.render('error/404');
    }
});

// description: Process add form
//@route POST /markets

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
    console.log(req.body);
    await Market.create(req.body);
    res.redirect('markets');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.render('error/500');
    }
    
});

// END ADD --------------------------------

//Description Show one market
// @ route GET /markets/:id

router.get('/:marketId', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const market = await Market.findById(req.params.marketId).lean();
        
        const products = await Product.find({market:req.params.marketId}).sort({category: 'asc'})
                                        .lean();
        
        res.render('markets/marketfull', {
            market,
            products
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.render('error/404');
    }
});


router.get('/hola', (req, res ) => {
    res.send('pika pika');
}); // --> When I access this route i get this error 
    // { CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "hola" at path "_id" for model "Market"

module.exports = router;
```

However the code works when the route /hola is written above the route for /:marketId

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Market = require('../models/Market');
const Product = require('../models/Product');

const productRouter = require('./product');

router.use('/:marketId/products', productRouter);

// Description Show all Markets
// @route GET /markets

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const markets = await Market.find().lean();
        res.render('markets/index', {
            markets
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.render('error/404');
    }
});

// ADD --------------------------------

// description: Show add market page
//@route GET /markets/add

router.get('/add', (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.render('markets/add');
    } catch (err) {
        res.render('error/404');
    }
});

// description: Process add form
//@route POST /markets

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
    console.log(req.body);
    await Market.create(req.body);
    res.redirect('markets');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.render('error/500');
    }
});

// END ADD --------------------------------

//Description Show one market
// @ route GET /markets/:id

router.get('/hola', (req, res ) => {
    res.send('pika pika'); // --> pika pika gets sent
});


router.get('/:marketId', async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const market = await Market.findById(req.params.marketId).lean();
        
        const products = await Product.find({market:req.params.marketId}).sort({category: 'asc'})
                                        .lean();
        
        res.render('markets/marketfull', {
            market,
            products
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.render('error/404');
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: `/hola` and `/:marketId` are basically the same route. When you send a request to `/hola`, express thinks `hola` is the marketId. Express routes are a stack, meaning the first route that matches the request will handle the request. That's why putting `/hola` first makes it work. Route order matters.

Comment: @EricGuan Oh I see now. Thank you very much for your explanation I forgot Route order mattered!